# Interface inheritance with an internal base

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I was wondering if there's a way to accomplish the following:

In my project, I have defined an interface, let's say IFruit. This interface has a public method GetName(). I also declare an interface IApple which implements IFruit and exposes some other method like GetAppleType() or something. There are more fruits like IBanana, ICherry, whatever.

Now on the outside, I want only to be able to use the actual fruit implementations and not IFruit itself. But I cannot declare the IFruit interface as private or internal, since the inherited interfaces will then say "cannot implement because the base class is less accessible".

I know this is possible with abstract implementations, but that's not an option in this case: I really need to use interfaces. Is there such an option?

**Update**
I guess my example need some clarification :) I use MEF to load interface implementations. The loaded collections are based upon IApple, IBanana, ICherry, etc. But IFruit itself is useless, I can't use classes based on only that interface. So I was looking for a way to prevent other developers from implementing solely IFruit, thinking that their class will be loaded (which it won't). So basically, it comes down to:

```
internal interface IFruit
{
  public string GetName();
}
```

public interface IApple : IFruit
{
  public decimal GetDiameter();
}

public interface IBanana : IFruit
{
  public decimal GetLenght();
}

But that won't compile due to the less accessible base interface.

Comment: What is the point of the interface if you dont want to use it?

Comment: The fact that each fruit interface will share a common set of methods they all need to have. Internally, my project uses the interface. I just want the outside world not to be able to implement it. 

Some parts of this solution are loaded with MEF. And the 'base interface' which specifies the common methods isn't an interface type which is actually loaded. So when a fellow programmer makes a fault an implements IFruit, his work won't get loaded. I want to prevent that fault.

Comment: If you really want to do this then it simply sounds to me like you need wrappers.... publicly expose only those things which should be public, then when you use them internally you wrap them with your internal wrappers that implement your internal interfaces. (Yes this means you have to add `GetName();` to every specific fruit and have a separate wrapper for each... but that would be the only way that is clean from an outside API perspective...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't really possible to do what you're trying, but you can put people off using the IFruit interface with an `[Obsolete]` attribute, with message to say why.

On your IBanana, IApple, ... interfaces, disable the obsolete warning from appearing.

```
[Obsolete]
public interface IFruit {
    ...
}

#pragma warning disable 612
public interface IBanana : IFruit {
    ...
}
#pragma warning restore 612
```

Comment: Not such a bad idea. With a check-in policy which prevents code with warnings from being checked in, this would indeed prevent using the interface at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

One way that you can guarantee this doesn't happen unintentionally is to make `IFruit` `internal` to your assembly and then use some adaptor to wrap the type appropriately:

```
public interface IApple { string GetName(); }
public interface IBanana { string GetName(); }

internal interface IFruit { string GetName(); }

class FruitAdaptor: IFruit
{
    public FruitAdaptor(string name) { this.name = name; }
    private string name;
    public string GetName() { return name; }
}

// convenience methods for fruit:
static class IFruitExtensions
{
    public static IFruit AsFruit(this IBanana banana)
    {
        return new FruitAdaptor(banana.GetName());
    }

    public static IFruit AsFruit(this IApple apple)
    {
        return new FruitAdaptor(apple.GetName());
    }
}
```

Then:

```
MethodThatNeedsFruit(banana.AsFruit());
```

You could also easily extend this to lazily call `GetName` on the adapted object, if the name could change over time.

---

Another option could be to have a DEBUG-only check that *does* load all `IFruit` implementers, and then throws an exception if one of them doesn't actually implement `IBanana`/`IApple`. Since it sounds like these classes are for internal use inside your company, this should stop anyone from accidentally implementing the wrong thing.

Comment: I guess that would work, but it doesn't really help the readability of the code. I'm going with the other solution which I like better, but have upvoted this one for others to see. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, but it's about the only way I could think of to make it impossible (disregarding malicious code, of course).

Answer (score 0):

If you have somewhow in your code (assuming that I correctly understand your state), something  like this:

```
public class WaterMellon : IFruit, IVegetables...
{
}
```

and you want to be able to consumer of your framework access **only** to a methods of `IFruit`, there is no other known method to me then simply cast.

```
IFruit fruit = new WaterMelon();
fruit. //CAN ACCESS ONLY TO FRUIT IMPLEMNTATION AVAILABLE IN WATERMELON
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.